# I am trying to make a flutter app to control my Philips Hue lights and I'm having problems with hue_dart

Tags: flutter, dart, philips-hue

I have Philips Hue lights and I want to be able to change the colour using Dart and Flutter. I have tried using a library called [`hue_dart`](https://pub.dev/packages/hue_dart) but when I run it as a Dart file, it can only control one light and I have to click the button on the Bridge every time.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:hue_dart/hue_dart.dart';

main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final client = Client();

  final discovery = BridgeDiscovery(client);

  List<DiscoveryResult> discoverResults = await discovery.automatic();
  final discoveryResult = discoverResults.first;

  var bridge = Bridge(client, discoveryResult.ipAddress);

  final whiteListItem = await bridge.createUser('dart_hue#example');

  bridge.username = whiteListItem.username;

  List<Light> lights = await bridge.lights();

  final light = lights.first.changeColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 1.0);
  LightState state = lightStateForColorOnly(light);
  state = state.rebuild(
    (s) => s
      ..on = true
      ..brightness = 10,
  );
  await bridge.updateLightState(light.rebuild(
    (l) => l..state = state.toBuilder(),
  ));
}
```

How would I make a user that persists? And one that can control an array of lights, not just the first one it returns?

Answer (score 1):

You have to click the Bridge button each time as you are creating a user that needs physical authorisation each time. Print the created username to display the randomly generated username that the Bridge has created.

```
final whiteListItem = await bridge.createUser('dart_hue#example');
print(whiteListItem);
bridge.username = whiteListItem.username;
```

Then you can get rid of the createUser step, and use that random string as the username as that is now an authorised user on the Bridge.

```
//final whiteListItem = await bridge.createUser('dart_hue#example');
bridge.username = 'the printed value'
```

As for the controlling one light aspect, you are only ever changing the state of the first light that is returned from the GET with `lights.first`. I haven't tried it but iterating through would be a good next step:

```
Set<Light> set = Set.from(lights);
set.forEach((element) => 
  changeState(element)
);
```